# ImportError : bad magic number in 'standlalone_package' : b'\x03\xf3\r\n in pyinstaller exe file

Tags: python, package, pyinstaller

I have this following directory

[image]

here i am trying to create a pyinstaller package of `standalone_package`, `loader.py` is my initiator on which i am using the pyinstaller command to generate the required directories.

If i am working on my system it's working fine, but as soon as I am trying to run in someone other machine i am getting this following `ImportError`

[image]

What can be the possible reason for it?

As i have some relative imports in it,my `loader.py` looks like this which i felt like might be the reason behind the error i am getting

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"Q:\--\--\--\kartikey.s\python\tools\standlone_directory")

from standalone_package.standalone_package import stnd_initiator


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stnd_initiator.dir_initiate()
```

but the thing is if i don't append the path in `loader.py`, i am getting this following error in pyinstaller generated exe

[image]